# Copy all TypeScript files to output directory after each build

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a bunch of TypeScript files in my project, and I want them all to be copied to the output directory on each build, preserving their structure. Here's what I've tried, but it does not work:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <TypeScriptFiles Include="Scripts\*.ts" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="CopyTypeScriptsToOutput">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(TypeScriptFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(OutputDir)\Scripts" />
</Target>
```

I've also used `Include="Scripts\**\*.ts"` but no success. What could be wrong?

Comment: I didn't check it yet. I'll check it and if it worked I'll mark it as answer. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've also used Include="Scripts***.ts" but no success. What could be
>   wrong?

The contents of the `Include` are the relative path of the files in your project.

**The main problem is that you did not specify how the target runs.** If you only use the Build UI to build your project, the target will not run. You should add build dependencies to the target, usually like [BeforeTargets and AfterTargets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/target-build-order?view=vs-2019#beforetargets-and-aftertargets), so that you run the target at build time.

**Second, you have a problem with the properties of the target generated path like** `$(OutputDir)`. I tried to test this property in vs2015,2017,2019, MSBuild does not have this property by default. If the property is not defined by yourself, the value will never be reached. So I recommend that you can use `$(OutputPath)` and `$(OutputDir)`.

**In addition**, please place `TypeScriptFiles` in the target to prevent confusion when the csproj file is first loaded. If you define it globally, it will be recognized by the system and mapped to the project again.

**Sample**

This is the target that I successfully completed.

```
 <Target Name="CopyTypeScriptsToOutput" AfterTargets="Build">
   <ItemGroup>
    <TypeScriptFiles Include="Scripts\*.ts" />
   </ItemGroup>

   <Copy SourceFiles="@(TypeScriptFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)\Scripts" />
</Target>
```

Hope it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

in my `package.json`, I ma using `cpx` to copy files in the `dist` folder

```
  "scripts": {
    "copy-media": "$(npm bin)/cpx media/**/*.* dist/media",
    "build": "tsc && yarn copy-media",
  },
```

So it builds first `tsc`, and then copy all files from folder media to `dist`